# Undefined symbols to framework when building application separated to library and application part

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have application separated into library part and the Application which links with the library.
Library uses `AFNetworking`, and thus requires `SystemConfiguration` and `MobileCoreServices` frameworks. They are added to build process and library builds nicely.

Why I need to add the same frameworks to my the Application part in order to build properly and not to see linking errors?

Is it not enough to link only with library?

Comment: yo need to add these framework because that library need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the library is a static library. You are only adding the frameworks when building the static library in order to access the include files; you are not linking with the frameworks.  This is because a static library is not linked when it's built; it's simply a collection of object files.  Try this from the command line to list the object files:

```
$ ar t /path/to/my/library.a
```

When the static library is linked with the app binary you must provide the libraries and frameworks of both, just as if the object files in the static library had been part of the app binary source tree.

Just think of the static library a simple collection of object files and it should make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's iOS frameworks contain [dynamic shared libraries](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html). AFAIK, when our app launches there is a process which gets created and dynamic shared libraries that the process is linked with gets loaded in to the memory. If the dynamic shared libraries are already loaded in the memory(for some other app process), they are shared with our app process. This is per process activity.

Since the static library is linked as part of the application binary itself and does not create a separate process, it becomes necessary to inform the runtime to load the frameworks that the static lib links with. Hence it is logical to add the frameworks used by static library in the application as well.